# How to implement a custom sorting in solr using external database data(eg. user's rating data)?

Tags: solr

I hava a problem with solr,i wanna sort the search result by the fields in solr's document and 
some fields in db. is there anybody who can help me，thanks！

Answer (score 0):

Add those fields you have in your database to Solr, then let Solr do the sorting.